# How to create JPEG file from Numpy array and upload it to AWS S3 using boto3?

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a Numpy array in memory that represents an image. I want to upload it to AWS S3 using boto3.

I have tried 4 different approaches:

```py
import numpy as np
import boto3
from PIL import Image

# Mock image
np_image = np.zeros((height, width, channels), dtype=np.uint8) 

# 1st approach - using io.BytesIO()
image = io.BytesIO(np_image)

# 2nd approach - using PIL.Image
image = Image.fromarray(np_image)

# 3rd approach - using io.BytesIO() and PIL.Image
image = Image.fromarray(np_image)
byte_io = io.BytesIO()
image.save(byte_io, format="jpeg")

# Upload image using boto3
s3.upload_fileobj(
    Fileobj=image,
    Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
    ExtraArgs={
        "ContentType": "image/jpeg"
    }
)
```

None of that worked as I'm getting error **ValueError: Fileobj must implement read**..

So far the only thing that's "worked" is the following:

```py
# 4th approach - using tobytes() from numpy.ndarray

io.BytesIO(np_image.tobytes())
```

With this approach the file is successfully uploaded. However, the file is corrupted as this is shown when I open the image:

[image: Uploaded Image]

One solution is saving the file in disk and then uploading it, but I believe that's not efficient.

Comment: Please click [edit] and include a proper [mcve]. That means you put the necessary `import` statements, you create a simple image with Numpy (it can be as easy as a red rectangle 60x80 pixels) and show your attempt to make a PNG and upload it. Then show the error messages. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to both create the image file and upload that file to S3.  One method is to call `Image.save()`, save the data to a in-memory buffer, than use `S3.put_object()` to upload that data:

```
# Create a simple array, with red in the top left corner, 
# and blue in the bottom right corner
import numpy
np_array = numpy.zeros((100, 100, 3), numpy.uint8)
np_array[0:40, 0:40] = (255, 0, 0)
np_array[60:100, 60:100] = (0, 0, 255)

# Generate the image file
from PIL import Image
import io
im = Image.fromarray(np_array)
bits = io.BytesIO()
im.save(bits, "png")

# Upload this file to S3
import boto3
# Seek back to the beginning of the file
bits.seek(0, 0)
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
# Make the file public for this demo, and set the content type
s3.put_object(
    Bucket=example_bucket, Key=example_key, 
    Body=bits, 
    ACL="public-read", ContentType="image/png",
)
```

Comment: The missing part for me was that I was not using `bits.seek(0, 0)`, which positions the cursor to the beginning of the buffer. Thanks!